# Combine fileskip0 and stepskip0 in org mode clock tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table, org-clock

Is it possible to combine `:stepskip0` and `:fileskip0` in org mode clock tables?

I can skip files with :`fileskip0`:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope agenda :block thisweek :step day :fileskip0

Daily report: [2015-12-28 Mon]
| File | Headline         | Time   |
|------+------------------+--------|
|      | ALL *Total time* | *0:00* |

Daily report: [2015-12-29 Tue]
| File             | Headline         | Time   |      |
|------------------+------------------+--------+------|
|                  | ALL *Total time* | *0:46* |      |
|------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| housekeeping.org | *File time*      | *0:46* |      |
|                  | Housekeeping     | 0:46   |      |
|                  | \emsp Reading    |        | 0:46 |

Daily report: [2015-12-30 Wed]
| File | Headline         | Time   |
|------+------------------+--------|
|      | ALL *Total time* | *0:00* |
```

And I can exclude empty days with `:stepskip0`:

```
Daily report: [2015-12-29 Tue]
| File                  | Headline         | Time   |      |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
|                       | ALL *Total time* | *0:46* |      |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| cba.org               | *File time*      | *0:00* |      |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| consultations.org     | *File time*      | *0:00* |      |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| cranberry.org         | *File time*      | *0:00* |      |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| housekeeping.org      | *File time*      | *0:46* |      |
|                       | Housekeeping     | 0:46   |      |
|                       | \emsp Reading    |        | 0:46 |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| journal.org           | *File time*      | *0:00* |      |
|-----------------------+------------------+--------+------|
```

What I'd like is both at once, i.e.:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope agenda :step day :block thisweek :stepskip0 :fileskip0

Daily report: [2015-12-29 Tue]
| File             | Headline         | Time   |      |
|------------------+------------------+--------+------|
|                  | ALL *Total time* | *0:46* |      |
|------------------+------------------+--------+------|
| housekeeping.org | *File time*      | *0:46* |      |
|                  | Housekeeping     | 0:46   |      |
|                  | \emsp Reading    |        | 0:46 |
```

So empty days and 0-time rows are both excluded. It seems that org only considers the first `:*skip0` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my mistake. `:fileskip0` and `:stepskip0` work on their own with or without an explicitly set value, but to use them together you need to supply the value:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :step day :block thisweek :stepskip0 t :fileskip0 t
```

I was working from some examples I'd found online that omitted the value.